# Dynamic Topic model output - Blei format

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I am working with the Dynamic Topic Models package that was developed by Blei. I am new to LDA however I understand it.

I would like to know what does the output by the name of
`lda-seq/topic-000-var-obs.dat` store?

I know that `lda-seq/topic-001-var-e-log-prob.dat` stores the log of the variational posterior and by applying the exponential over it, I get the probability of the word within Topic 001.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Topic-000-var-e-log-prob.dat store the log of the variational posterior of the topic 1.

Topic-001-var-e-log-prob.dat store the log of the variational posterior of the topic 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have failed to find a concrete answer anywhere. However, since the documentation's `sample.sh` states

```
The code creates at least the following files:
- topic-???-var-e-log-prob.dat: the e-betas (word distributions) for topic ??? for all times.  
...
- gam.dat
```

without mentioning the `topic-000-var-obs.dat` file, suggests that it is not imperative for most analyses.

#### Speculation

`obs` suggest observations. After a little dig around in the `example/model_run` results, I plotted the sum across epochs for each word/token using:

```
temp = scan("dtm/example/model_run/lda-seq/topic-000-var-obs.dat")
temp.matrix = matrix(temp, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE) 
plot(rowSums(temp.matrix))
```

and the result is something like:

[image: row sums]

The general trend of the non-negative values is decreasing and many values are floored (in this case to `-11.00972 = log(1.67e-05)`) Suggesting that these values are weightings or some other measure of influence on the model. The model removes some tokens and the influence/importance of the others tapers off over the index. The later trend may be caused by preprocessing such as sorting tokens by tf-idf when creating the dictionary.

Interestingly the row sum values varies for both the floored tokens and the set with more positive values:

[image: different example]

```
temp = scan("~/Documents/Python/inference/project/dtm/example/model_run/lda-seq/topic-009-var-obs.dat")
temp.matrix = matrix(temp, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE) 
plot(rowSums(temp.matrix))
```